# how to add fix size of tab bar using sherlockactionbar in android? It should not going out of screen

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I am using *actionbarsherlock* in my android project. I have added tabs but the last tab going out of screen.

my problem is I don't want to be last tab out of screen. I wanted to fit all tabs in screen using *actionbarsherlock*.

Please help me. If any one have answer to this problem. I am stuck on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with the layout in your xml. Keep in mind that your text will make your tabs wider and could still cause the problem. The maximum tabs is around 5 without sliding out of your screen.

```
<style name="DefaultTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/default_ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/default_ActionBarTabStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="default_ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item> 
</style>
```